# Build PCL on macOS Sierra - Linking CXX shared library error: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: xcode, cmake, macos-sierra, point-cloud-library, dylib

I'm trying to install PCL (Point Cloud Library) on my system with macOS Sierra following the instructions here: http://ns50.pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/compiling_pcl_macosx.php

I made it to the step "Building PCL" but receive the following error when running the "cmake .." command:

```
[ 10%] Linking CXX shared library ../lib/libpcl_io.dylib
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
 "boost::this_thread::hiden::sleep_until(timespec const&)", referenced from:
   pcl::HDLGrabber::readPacketsFromPcap() in hdl_grabber.cpp.o
   pcl::OpenNIGrabber::start() in openni_grabber.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see 
invocation)
make[2]: *** [lib/libpcl_io.1.8.0.99.dylib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [io/CMakeFiles/pcl_io.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Thanks for your help!